# dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error when installing ImageTK

Tags: raspbian, apt, dpkg

I get the following error when installing ImageTK.

```
% sudo apt-get install python-pil python-imaging python-imaging-tk

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-pil is already the newest version.
Suggested packages:
  python-pil-doc python-pil.imagetk-dbg
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python-imaging python-imaging-tk python-pil.imagetk
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 41 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/31.7 kB of archives.
After this operation, 111 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package python-imaging.
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'linux-libc-dev:armhf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package 'qdbus' is missing final newline
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what version you are using. This answer is for Raspbian stretch. You should first upgrade:

```
pi ~$ sudo apt update
pi ~$ sudo apt full-upgrade
```

Then install packets separate. No need to install `python-pil`. This will be install automatically with `python-imaging`. `python-imaging-tk` is only a virtual packet and will install `python-pil.imagetk`. So do it direct:

```
pi ~$ sudo apt install python-imaging
pi ~$ sudo apt install python-pil.imagetk
```

If then there are still missing packets try to install them. At least you can clean up your apt-lists. But this should be done with caution. Afterwards repeat the commands from beginning.

```
pi ~$ sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

You have also to address the repositories, at least these two:

```
pi ~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi

pi ~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list
deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ stretch main ui
```